# sed: what to do with backslash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to change one of its lines by `sed` but at the end of that line there is a backslash:

```
Some Text that should be changed \
```

I Used:

```
sed -i "s/$line/$newline/" $MyFile
```

sed says:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unknown option to `s'
sed: -e expression #1, char 84: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: What is in `$line`?  What is in `$newline`?  You double up the occurrences of backslash to match a single backslash.

Comment: What are `$line` and `$newline` (echo them out and let us know?)

Comment: of course $line is the line: "Some Text that should be changed \" and $newline is the new line, what I want to write instead of that line.

Comment: Does the `$newline` value contain any slashes or backslashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first escape the string you're using inside the `sed` command, with something like:

```
line=$(echo $line | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')
```

This will turn it from:

```
Some Text that should be changed \
```

into:

```
Some Text that should be changed \\
```

which will stop it from escaping the final delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have:

```
line="Some Text that should be changed \\"
```

so your `echo "$line"` yields:

```
Some Text that should be changed \
```

Then `sed` sees:

```
sed -i "s/Some Text that should be changed \/Your replacement/" yourfile
```

and the backslash means that your search pattern hasn't ended, and therefore the substitute command is malformed - as the error message says.

You will have to get a second backslash onto the end of the string.  One of a myriad ways of doing that is:

```
case "$line" in
(*\\)  line="$line\\";;
esac
```

This is just being inventive...but it has the merit of not executing any external command to fix the string.  There are also more direct substitutions available in `bash`.

Now you can do:

```
sed -i "s/^$line$/$newline/" $myFile
```

and as long as `$newline` contains neither any slashes nor any backslashes, you will be safe enough.

Answer (score 1):

One probable cause is that your `$line` or `$newline` contains the delimiter `/`.

Please try some other delimiters that do not occur in your patterns.

E.g.

```
sed -i "s@$line@$newline@" $MyFile
sed -i "s#$line#$newline#" $MyFile
```

-- edit according to @paxdiablo's comments.

The variable name `$line` misleads. It should be a **pattern** instead.

So you must make sure it's a valid pattern, in which a backslash `\` should be escaped with `\\`

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure a delimiter change will help here because the string being used, `$line`, ends with `\` - that means it will escape _any_ delimiter.

Comment: @paxdiablo You are right. The variable name `$line` misleads. It should be a `$pattern` instead.